# Create & send DHCP packets with source address 0.0.0.0 in Mac OS

Tags: sockets, ip, dhcp, bsd, raw-sockets

I’m trying to create and send DHCP REQUEST message over a raw socket on Mac OS X. I’m able to create and send a well formatted message with the exception of the Source IP address. It should be 0.0.0.0.

Wireshark indicates the source address is whatever I set in the ip_src.s_addr field of the IP header, unless I use 0.0.0.0. When I use 0.0.0.0 Wireshark shows the IP as the machine sending the packet. FWIW, I can set destination IP to 255.255.255.255 no problem.

How do I set the source IP to 0.0.0.0?

Also what is the purpose of sin_addr.s_addr field used in sin parameter passed to the sendto function? Changing it or leaving it unset seems to have no effect.

Code:

```
int s = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
if (s < 0)
{
   perror("Failed to create raw socket");
   exit(1);
}    
if (setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on)) < 0)
{
   perror("Failed to set raw socket options");
   exit(1);
}

memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
sin.sin_port = htons(67);
inet_pton(AF_INET, "255.255.255.255", &sin.sin_addr);

if (sendto (s, DHCPPacket, DHCPPacketLength,  0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof (struct sockaddr)) < 0)
{
   perror("sendto failed");
   exit(-1);
}
else
{
   printf ("Packet Send. Length : %d Payload size: %d Options size: %d\n", DHCPPacketLength, sizeof(DHCPmsgType),sizeof(DHCP_VendorType));
}
```

Comment: When you refer to the `sin_addr.s_addr` field, do you mean the `siaddr` field, which is the "_IP address of next server to use in bootstrap; returned in DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK by server?_" _[RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt)_ explains what all the fields are in Section 2 Protocol Summary.

Comment: No that's not what I'm referring to. The 5th parameter of the sendto() function takes a sockaddr struct (I'm casting from a sockaddr_in struct). That struct includes an IP address but doesn't seem to have any effect.